# Extracting the hex value after after converting a given byte array into blob obj in Java

Tags: java, blob

I have a requirement to insert blob value into one of the tables(DB type - Oracle). I am using Java to convert my image file into a byte array first and then to blob object by using javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob.
However, when I create a blob object using

```
Blob  blob = new SerialBlob(byteArray);
```

The resulting blob object is of the form `javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@'some-hex-value'`. When I use the blob object in my insert query, Oracle gives me: `Invalid hex number` error.

But when I try to insert using only the hex part and removing 'javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob' part from my blob object, the insert query works fine and the record gets inserted.

So is there any way to extract the hex value from the blob object that I am converting my image file into?

Thanks!

Comment: try using `setBinaryStream` while inserting into blob. `byte[] pictureBytes = ...; prepStmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureBytes), pictureBytes.length);`

Comment: @guleryuz May I ask what object is `prepStmt`? Because when I want to apply `setBinaryStream` method to my converted blob object of type `Blob`, it only takes single argument. Method is: `setBinaryStream(long pos)`.

Comment: it is `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.  `PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
 

statement.setBinaryStream(1,new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureBytes),pictureBytes.length);
statement.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @guleryuz First of all, thanks for the reply. The community is quite helpful. Anyway, Will definitely try that as soon as possible as I am stuck with some other task on priority.